# Inserting current user ID into Post for Author

Tags: users, wp-insert-post

I am trying to insert the `user id` of the current user when creating a `custom post type`. This is my code:

```
$my_post = array(
            'post_title' => $orderRequestCode.' - ' . $customerName,
            'post_content' => $orderContent,
            'post_status' => 'draft',
            'post_author' => $user_ID,
            'post_type' => 'orders'
        );

wp_insert_post( $my_post);
```

I get a reference to the user as well: `$user_ID = $user->ID;`

However, it is not inserting anything into the Author field when I Check on the `back-end`. 
Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing your code is inside a function and `$user` is not defined. More importantly, there's no need for you to set `post_author` - WordPress will automatically use the current logged-in user by default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the global variable for the user ID (if you actually need to use it) somewhat like this:

```
global $user_ID;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

The get_currentuserinfo() call will populate the global $user_ID variable which you can then use directly, as you have it in your args currently.

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)